# Docker volume mounts with empty contents with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm able to mount a directory with specific files to docker-compose'd containers. My Docker which runs on HyperV. But on my team members are unable to mount this directory.

The same docker-compose file is used. The only difference is my docker runs on HyperV and my team members on VirtualBox. So maybe it's this difference that causes the issue?

I thought of creating the volume using `docker volume create ...` But I couldn't understand how I link it to an existing directory with content.

Here is a snippet of my docker-compose.yml. Any point of direction is appreciated.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    service1:
        ...
        volumes:
            - type: volume
              source: ./volume
              target: /opt/volume/
```

Comment: change `type: volume` to `type: bind` and see if it works

Comment: I tried that, didn't work

Comment: Try short syntax `./volume:/opt/volume/`. I assume in both cases volume directory is available with content in the local directory

Comment: It is available. I also tried that, didn't work. I think I tried it in every possible format. Is there a way to debug it ?

Comment: you are running the command inside virtualbox or from outside the virtualbox?

Comment: Which command? the docker-compose (up | down build) ones? outside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153752/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-aclokay).

Answer (score 0):

create a **docker-compose.yml** files

Create a custom path volume and run your application in swarm mode

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        image: app
        volumes:
            - data-logs:/var/wslogs

volumes:
  data-logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /my/host/path/logs/
```