# the behavior of volume Mode between docker-compose and docker cli

Tags: docker, docker-compose

1-a. Run container with docker cli with volume "/var/run/docker.sock"

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock hoge
```

1-b. Run docker inspect, Mounts.Mode shows "" (shows empty)

```
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
            "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
```

2-a. Run container with docker-compose

```
services:
node-red:
    container_name: hoge
    image: hoge/hoge
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

2-b. Run docker inspect, Mounts.mode shows "rw"

```
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
            "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
```

is there any way to mount volume in empty mode (e,g, 1-b) with docker-compose?

Comment: Beyond this difference in very low-level debugging output, are you seeing any functional differences?  I'd expect both setups to be able to use the host's Docker daemon (and start other containers, create their own volumes, edit arbitrary files on the host, _etc._).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068094/docker-volume-mounts-with-empty-contents-with-docker-compose